# How to process SQL results into a CSV/Excel attachment using JCL?

Tags: excel, csv, jcl

Is there a way to export a data from a dataset to an excel/csv file having it properly included in spreadsheet column using JCL?

I have a query which extracts data from a table into a dataset file. This data has a description column and it contains both semi-colons and commas.

It is being ftp'ed to be exported to CSV/excel file, and then directly sent to an email address.

JCL Step:

```
//STEP003  EXEC PGM=IKJEFT1B,DYNAMNBR=20               
//SYSEXEC  DD DSN=SYS2.PRODUCTS.REXX,DISP=SHR         
//SYSTSIN  DD *              
%XMITIP ( USER@EMAIL.COM ) -                  
HTML                       -                    
 SUBJECT "REPORT AS OF &DATE"                   
 MSGDD EHMESG                                   
 FILEDD (REPORT)                                
 FORMAT CSV                                     
 FILENAME (REPORT.CSV)                          
FROM USER@EMAIL.COM                                  
 //REPORT DD DSN=USER.TEST.REPORT,DISP=SHR     
 //EHMESG DD *                       
 REPORT
```

We would like it to be quicker than manually extracting data and putting it in excel sheet then manually separating the data by columns.

Any input is welcome or using other language. We could take the SQL Query --> Data --> CSV --> FTP --> CSV/Excel --> send email attached csv/excel file in one program execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sort utility (DFSORT) has the ability to create CSV files through the JFY and SQZ suboperations of the BUILD keyword on the OUTREC statement. I’ll be the first to admit it’s a bit complicated, but IBM performance expert Martin Packer wrote [this article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/MartinPacker/entry/using_dfsort_to_create_csv) 12 years ago that explains it very well. His contrived input data contains four-byte binary fields, but there’s enough basic information in it to use as a starting point.

Your flow would be SQL query->flat file->DFSORT->CSV->XMITIP.

Comment: Hi Zarchasmopgmr. Thank you for the response. I tried to check the article but it seem it didn't take into consideration the data if it have included comma as real value (IE. Descition/Addresses/ETC), and how specifically it will be detected in CSV and be set in column properly.

Comment: You can put the comma inside quotes, like "MY NAME","123 FIFTH ST, APT. 17","SOMETOWN"